# How can I create a Draw Search Area with the bottom closed like Yelp.com?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wrote the following code in version 3 of the API:

```
  var polyOptions = {
      strokeWeight: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0.45,
      editable: true
    };
    // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
    // markers, lines, and shapes.
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
      },
      rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
        // mouses down on it.
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);
      }
    });

    // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
    // map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

    buildColorPalette();
}
```

It's going to take some work, but I want custom Draw Search Areas like Yelp. I need the bottom closed and I want to remove the control of the draw. And I need an external link for rectangle draw like Yelp out of the map Draw Search Area.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the math.  Here is a start:

Using either Spherical Law of Cosines, or Haversine, calculate the rectangle bounds and then check which of your markers are in the bounds.